# How to determine if an entity was created in the current session?

Tags: java, hibernate

Imagine a fairly complex server call spanning multiple components all wrapped in a single transaction. One component can create new entities with `saveOrUpdate`. Another component has access to this entity, but needs to know if it was created in this session or before. How can I achieve it?

Ideally, looking for a boolean call like `wasCreatedInThisSession` below:

```
public void myTransactionalMethod() {
    MyEntity e1 = session.load(MyEntity.class, 15);
    session.wasCreatedInThisSession(e1); // -> false
    MyEntity e2 = new MyEntity("Test");
    session.saveOrUpdate(e2);
    session.wasCreatedInThisSession(e2); // -> true
}
```

Comment: sorry, i'm not realy into hybernate, but try session.createQuery(query to find e1) ?

Comment: @TamásKüzdi After `saveOrUpdate` it may be present in database, so in the second case the query may return it as well.

Comment: You can try with contains(Object o) method in Session whether that particular object is associated with  current session or not.

Comment: @Seshagiri Does not help either - in the example above it is true for both calls.

Comment: Indeed yes.  By the way, for persisting the object either we have to call save or saveOrUpdate. And these has to explicitly invoke by the use.  So why cant you mark a flag for such object as it is created in this block?

Comment: My real case is nowhere near as simple. Wondering if it's supported in Hibernate, or I have to wrap or intercept all calls to `save` / `saveOrUpdate` and remember what was created myself.